# Error: package 'rqt_graph' not found

Tags: ros, rqt-graph, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people!

i almost finish my first program with ROS and I want to watch  the map with nodes and topic, but when I use `rqt_graph` I get this error returns

```
Error: package 'rqt_graph' not found
```

I am using this instruccion

```
rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
```

maybe the instruccion is wrong, I don't sure.

anybody can help me?

---

Edit: I try to install it, but not the package is located

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rqt
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rqt-graph
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugins
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247423/error:-package-%27rqt_graph%27-not-found/) by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-11-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you have rqt_graph installed? It doesn't look like it. Did you try installing it using (for indigo) `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rqt-graph` or for kinetic `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt-graph`?

---

Edit:

> I try to install it, but not the package is located

Do you have your sources setup correctly? Perhaps `sudo apt-get update` will do the trick if you have, otherwise, look at the instructions from the [indigo installation guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) to find out how to configure your repositories and setup sources and keys.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4